# Q: Slew Rate of MCP601

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using the [MCP601](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21314g.pdf) for rectification of small AC signals. I got it working.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1cAr2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

however at high frequencies (20kHz) weird behavior starts to surface such as this.
[image]

I understand is has something to do with the chip spending too long in saturation and can't catch up. I also heard that you can get a faster OP AMP in terms of slew rate and it would fix the problem as well.

But shouldn't this OP AMP Already be suitable as the Slew rate equation is \$2*\pi*F\$

if we do the math

\$SR = 2*\pi * 20kHz\$

\$SR = 0.1256V/uS\$ the op amp is stated for 2.3V/uS ?

Can anyone explain to me why is this is happening with this op amp? and why isnt the current slew rate satisfactory enough for this current application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The op-amp output has to go from saturation at 0V to +0.6 **instantly** to keep the rectified output from swinging below zero. That's because of the diode forward drop.

The op-amp recovery time from saturation is not specified by the slew rate, and in fact it's seldom specified at all. It can be much, much worse than you would think from the slew rate.

Eg. [LMV2011](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv2011.pdf) with slew rate of 4V/us but \$t_{rec}\$ recovery time from saturation of 50ms typical.

Comment: I see, I am assuming even the LMV2011 wouldn't be fast enough as T = 1/f right? T = 1/20kHz = 50us

Comment: No point in even thinking about it with 50 millisecond recovery

Comment: Yeah kk, just use it as a standard? How would a 45v/uS be ish?

Comment: and I would one fix the recovery time of an op amp? do we have to delay a signal for the op amp to catch up?

Comment: If you can't use a circuit that doesn't saturate, such as [this](https://wiki.analog.com/_detail/university/courses/alm1k/circuits1/alm-lab-precision-rectifier-f3.png?id=university%3Acourses%3Aalm1k%3Acircuits1%3Aalm-cir-precision-rectifier) one (requires a bipolar supply, but that's usually not a deal killer), use a different op-amp.

Comment: How do I choose an op amp that can meet my spec? As you mentioned not a lot of op amp state it's recovery time. How would I ago about this?

Comment: It's not a parameter that most people care about. **Pick one that does** specify recovery time such as OPA743 or use a better circuit. You'll still have the issue with the output slewing from 0 to 0.6V, but it won't be very important at audio frequencies.

Comment: Would this OP AMP suffice? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa350.pdf